# How to reset form after successful sent Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using Redux Form.

I want to reset Form if the data is sent successfully.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import CommentForm from '../components/CommentForm'; 
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {authHeader} from '../components/auth-header'; 
import $ from 'jquery';
import { reset, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const createBlogComment = (data) => {
    return fetch(CelestialSettings.URL.api + '/comments', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        ...authHeader(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        $('.thecmstatus').removeClass('success').addClass('error').html('There is something wrong while posting a comment');
        return false;
      }
      if (res.status === 400) {
        $('.thecmstatus').removeClass('success').addClass('error').html('There is something wrong while posting a comment');
        return false;
      }
      if (res.status === 201) {
        $('.thecmstatus').removeClass('error').addClass('success').html('Your comment will be visible after approval');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.thecmstatus').html(''); 
        }, 3000);
        return true;
      }
    }).catch(err => err);
}
class CommentFormToAPI extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 
    }
    handleSubmit(content) {
      let APIdata = {...this.props.addComment, content:content.commentcontent};
      createBlogComment(APIdata);
      if(createBlogComment(APIdata)){
        //I use this but it is wrong.
        dispatch(reset('CommentForm'));
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <CommentForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></CommentForm>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      addComment: state.addComment,
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(CommentFormToAPI));
```

I can handle the submission since API sent but I do not know how to reset Redux form. Can you please suggest me.

I took a look here and I use the last way (D).
https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/faq/howtoclear.md/

Update my screen log:
[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `dispatch` to your createBlogComment function:

`createBlogComment(APIdata, dispatch)`

Then, in case of `201` response:

```
if (res.status === 201) {
    $('.thecmstatus').removeClass('error').addClass('success').html('Your comment will be visible after approval');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.thecmstatus').html(''); 
    }, 3000);

    dispatch(reset('YourFormName'));

    return true;
}
```

Make sure to import `reset` function from `redux-form`.

Comment: Dispatch return undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: @HaiTien Your `CommentFormToAPI` component is connected. In `this.props` you will find `dispatch` function. Just pass it to the `createBlogComment` as the second argument and use it inside :)

Comment: CommentForm  is connected to Redux Form, not CommentFormToAPI. CommentFormToAPI is connected to my own reducer. So I do not know how to call reset :(

Comment: @HaiTien In your code sample it's clearly that `CommentFormToAPI` is connected

Comment: you are right. it is connect. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: @HaiTien You have dispatch in props. Pass it as the second argument and then inside function `const createBlogComment = (data, dispatch) => { ... dispatch(reset('CommentForm')) }`

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it ^^. It is so helpful.